# Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider Error in Google Mobile Ads SDK v17.0.0

Tags: android, admob

While upgrading to Google Mobile Ads SDK v17.0.0 i got an error (implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0')

```
Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider
```

How to fix this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in version 17.0.0, if you are an AdMob publisher you are now required to add your AdMob app ID in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-################~##########"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml